# When is an HTTP response finished?

Tags: .net, sockets, http, http-headers

I am writing a simple HTTP client in .NET for learning purposes. I am using the .NET [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) class, which ultimately uses [Winsock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock). I do not want to use the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx), [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), or [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) classes, as they use [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630.aspx), which I do not want to use as I am doing this for my own understanding of how HTTP works.

I am wondering how to determine when an HTTP response is finished. By reading the HTTP/1.1 specification ([RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)), I think the following pseudocode is how to determine when an HTTP response is finished.

```
parse HTTP headers
if parse not successful:
    throw error
if HTTP version is 1.1 and Transfer-encoding is chunked:
    parse first line of each chunk as an ASCII hexadecimal, the chunk size
    if parse not successful:
        throw error
    read each chunk until chunk size 0
else if Content-Length is specified:
    read Content-Length number of bytes
else:
    throw error
```

Is this a more-or-less correct approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [End of an HTTP Response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515565/end-of-an-http-response)

Comment: See RFC 2616 §4.4 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) for more cases to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct, with some minor corrections, per [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4):

```
Read and parse HTTP headers
if not successful:
    throw error
if response can contain message body:
    if HTTP version is 1.1+ and Transfer-encoding is not identity:
        while true:
            read line, extract delimited ASCII hexadecimal, the chunk size
            if not successful:
                throw error
             if chunk size is 0:
                break while loop
             read chunk size number of bytes
        read and parse trailing HTTP headers
    else if Content-Length is specified:
        read Content-Length number of bytes
    else if Content-Type is "multipart/byteranges":
        read and parse MIME-encoded chunks until terminating MIME boundary is reached
    else:
        read until connection is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-24.html#message.body.length (if this doesn't answer your question then please send back to the Working Group).