# How uTorrent can read the body of a http response message without a specified size or "chunked" option?

Tags: http, protocols, response, utorrent

I've used the SmartSniff tool to catch the http messages between the uTorrent application and a server. I found one server that sends "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" response messages with a body and no headers that can tell the length of the body or the "chunked" option, but uTorrent seems not having trouble with that, it works fine. And I wander how did it do it ?

I think that, maybe, uTorrent knows about this "server error" and when it is expecting a body, after it reads the response line and headers (in this case none), it reads until the server close the connection. Is this posible ?

Catched communication:

> - GET /announce.php?(a list of parameters here) HTTP/1.1
> - Host: some.server.here:1234
> - User-Agent: uTorrent/3320(30416)
> - Accept-Encoding: gzip
> - Connection: Close

- HTTP/1.0 200 OK
- (empty line)
- d8:completei176e10:incompletei0e8:intervali3600e5:peers0:e

Comment: possible duplicate of [End of an HTTP Response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515565/end-of-an-http-response)

Answer (score 0):

I researched the link provided and I find the answer. It is as follow:

> In a response message without a declared message body length, the message body length is determined by the number of octets received prior to the server closing the connection.